# Calling an overridden method from the base class

Tags: c++, methods, overriding

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class A {
 public:
  virtual void foo() {
    bar();
  }

 protected:
  virtual void bar() {
    // Do stuff
  }
}

class B : public A {
 protected:
  virtual void bar() {
    // Do other stuff
  }
}
```

If I have an instance of B and call the foo method, which bar method would get called? And is this compiler specific?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `A::foo` will call `B::bar` if you have an instance of `B`. It does not matter if the instance is referenced through a pointer or a reference to a base class: regardless of this, `B`'s version is called; this is what makes *polymorphic* calls possible. The behavior is not compiler-specific: virtual functions behave this way according to the standard.

Comment: Note that this behavior is not the case within the base constructor and destructor. There it will call the base implementation. Discussion: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/109477/

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can get around it. In this case you can add a `true` default bool argument to the A constructor, and pass a `false` to it in B:

```
class A 
{
public:
    A(bool construct = true) { 
        if (!construct) return;
        bar(); 
    }
    virtual void bar() { cout << "A::bar" << endl; }
};

class B : public A 
{
public:
    B() : A(false) { bar(); }
    void bar() override { cout << "B::bar" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

Output:

```
A::bar
B::bar
```